# Need optimized XSLT recursive template to strip html tags.

Tags: html, xslt, tags, strip

I am using the following template for removing the html tags from my `xml` content. It is working for few of the `xml`s but failing for the few `xml`s, with stack over flow error due to the recursive call. Can anybody provide the optimized solutions for the same?

```
<xsl:template name="strip-tags">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, '&lt;')">
            <xsl:value-of  select="substring-before($text, '&lt;')"/>
            <xsl:call-template name="strip-tags">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&gt;')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please include an example XML that causes infinite recursion.

Comment: I don't think the recursion is necessarily infinite; just big enough to blow the stack.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, The problem is with html conent of one of the tag. And that html is very big and can't paste here.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, The problem is with html conent of one of the tag of the xml. And that html is very big and can't paste here. This is having 613 html elements. Thanks, Raju

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could

(a) get yourself a processor that does tail call optimization (for example Saxon), or

(b) get yourself an XSLT 2.0 processor an rewrite this using xsl:analyze-string.

One other point, though: this code could recurse infinitely (in which case no optimizer will help you) if the angle brackets in the data aren't paired up as you expect, for example if there is a `<` character before the first '>' character.

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code for this? What is the best way of removing the html tags? If you have any code, please share with me. It will be a great help.

Comment: Hi Michael, If not the recursive call, do we have any other of removing the tags, which should not do the recursions. Thanks,

Comment: The only way to do this in XSLT 1.0 is with recursion. With XSLT 2.0 you can use xsl:analyze-string.

Comment: Do you have any samples of XSLT 2.0 xsl:analyze-string?

Comment: Could you please provide high level steps/logic to achieve this using xsl:analyze-string?

Comment: I would need to see a more detailed specification before sketching out any code.

Comment: Hi Machael, The html content is looking like below. &lt;p&gt;Remove HTML Tags&lt;/p&gt; . < is appearing as &lt; and > is appearing as &gt;. So in my template I have sub string based on &lt; and &gt; using substring-after and substring-before. So we need to follow the similar logic for this. To say in short way, we need to remove html tags from the content. Thanks, Raju.

Comment: There is no much specifications, only aim is to remove html tags. Thanks, Raju.

Comment: A few things you need to specify: (a) what do you mean by an "html tag". (b) what happens if invalid content is found, e.g. `<td<td>>`.

Comment: (a) I mean all the html elements like <p> </p> <span> </span> <table> </table> ... etc. (b) There is no chance of invalid html, as it is getting generated using a tool automatically. Don't worry about the invalid html. Just need to concentrate on removing the tags and displying plain text. Thanks a lot for the help your providing. Please let me know, if you need any more information. Thanks, Raju.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a risky strategy.  It'll recurse for EVERY element in the input, which could yield jillions of them and fill up the stack!  How about, template match on all the tag names, e.g. the below and just "don't copy" but copy everything else.  I found this on Pawson, http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N4554.html#d5769e474

`<xsl:template match=" a | abbr | acronym | address | applet | area | b | base | basefont | 
        bdo | big | blockquote  | body | br | button | caption | center | cite | code | col | 
        colgroup | dd | del | dfn | dir | div | dl | dt | em | fieldset     | font | form | 
        frame | frameset | h1 | h2 | h3 | h4 | h5 | h6 | head | hr | html | i | iframe | img | 
        input | ins | isindex    | kbd | label | legend | li | link | map | menu | meta | 
        noframes | noscript | object | ol | optgroup | option | p     | param | pre | q | s | 
        samp | script | select | small | span | strike | strong | style | sub | sup | table | 
        tbody | td | textarea | tfoot | th | thead | title | tr | tt | u | ul | var">`

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for the reply. Do we have any other of removing the html tags without getting the stack over flow error?

Comment: I would say both Michael Kay's and my responses are in the ballpark for this.  I recommend you just "forget about" the approach you mentioned above that causes stack overflows.